# Algorithm Graph depth - first search

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

This is graph code, I want to understand Depth-first search algorithm, but I had some problem with this code,

If I input params:

5 5 
1 2 
1 3 
 
1 5 
2 4 
3 5

Why cur become return 4 to 2 to 1 in function dfs?
thank your response

```
#include <stdio.h>
int book[101], sum,e[101][101];
int n,m,a,b;

void dfs(int cur){
    int i;
    printf("%d ",cur);

    sum++;
    if(sum==n){
        return;
    }

    // 
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        if( e[cur][i]==1 && book[i]==0 ){
            book[i]=1;
            dfs(i);
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main(){
    int i,j;
    scanf("%d %d ", &n,&m);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
            if(i==j){
                e[i][j] = 0;
            }else{
                e[i][j] = 99999999;
            }
        };
    };

    for(i=1;i<=m;i++){
        scanf("%d %d" ,&a, &b);
        e[a][b] = 1;
        e[b][a] = 1;
    }

    book[1] = 1;
    dfs(1);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)` is __wrong__ because arrays in C go from `0..n-1`.  Use: `for(i=0;i<n;i++)`

Comment: It is called "Depth-first _search_" but I don't see you searching anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're asking why your DFS is first exploring 1, then 2, then 4? Well, that's how a DFS works: It greedily goes to the next unvisited vertex. What output would you expect?

**Some remarks regarding your code:**

To improve the answers that you get, I'd suggest posting code that is *a lot* cleaner than the code in your question:

- Please use variable names that tell your readers what they mean. For example: Use something like `bool visited[]` instead of `int book[]`.
- Use the correct data type! If you want to store whether an edge is there or not, or whether a vertex was visited or not, use `bool`, not some magic `int` values.
- Global variables are usually not the right thing. There is no reason why all your variables should be global.
- Neither is there a reason why the arrays should have the constant size `101`.

Comment: Hello Lukas, this code is not my code, the code is book example code, I just paste code, wanna to know, how to do let 4 to 2 to 1 back to path。 thank your feedback。